# Append (0) on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

What is the function of zero on the append's bracket? I'm really wondering is it as the starter for appending or as the end of appending. And why? I need your help. thanks

```
 for node in range(self.V):
            parent.append(node)
            rank.append(0)
```

Comment: it will append value at end of the list

Comment: What is `rank`? Have you tried reading the documentation for `.append()`?

Comment: `rank` is a string list that defined before. And thanks, now I'm understand

Answer (score 1):

`append()` would append element 0 at the end of the list. The argument that append takes is the element to be appended at the end of the list.
For more information: check [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)